# MySQL view count and sum and other operations from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is my situation:

I have 4 tables that all contains a column called `score` in all of these tables my goal for a view to create operations to the result of the 4 tables  getting the following values:

- Total score
- Total number of rows
- average (total score / number of rows)

Now i know that i would be able to create the view as:

```
(SELECT * FROM table1 where condition) + (SELECT * FROM table2 where condition)
```

So on and so forth.

but for each of the three goals i have i would have to nested select all tables atleast 2 times.

So my question is how do you handle a case like this? is there any operation in sql that makes this an easy task or am i bound to do something redundant?

**Update**

So my full case is that every use in my system has something called a division_id now i want to use this ID to find out what the score is for each division:

[image]

(PLEASE IGNORE THE _COPY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a UNION to join the 4 tables, since there is no join condition.  There are a couple of ways that you could do this with the division field.  Probably the most concise is:

```
select division_id, count(*), avg(scores.score), sum(scores.score) from
  user join 
  (select id as user_id, score from user
   UNION ALL
   select user_id, score from test_score
   UNION ALL
   select user_id, score from task_score
   UNION ALL
   select user_id, score from offline_score) as scores
  on user.id = scores.user_id
  group by division_id
```

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e5fea2/2)

Comment: would this work if i joined the tables on a user table?

Comment: Please take a look at my Update would this still work?

Comment: this would require me to have a "score" column in my user table ?

Comment: It wouldn't.  I just thought there was a score column in the users table.  All you would need in the inner table is all of the tables with a score column